# Simple SQL update query not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to run this query but I get an error:

```
UPDATE wp_usermeta 
SET meta_value = "a:1:{s:16:\"client_special\";b:1;}" 
WHERE user_id = "1009";
```

But I get this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'UPDATE wp_usermeta
>   SET meta_value = "a:1:{s:16:\"cliente_especial\";b:1;}" W' at line 1

It is ok for me, I escaped the `"` with `\` character.

Comment: What DB platform? What are you running the query in (c# code, vbscript, query editor, something else)?

Comment: show you  query command  too

Comment: I run the query in Sequel Pro in the Query area.

Comment: Instead of escaping you could try simple quotes.

Comment: @kenfire not working. thanks.

Comment: instead of using double quotes, use single quote  SET meta_value = 'a:1:{s:16:\"client_special\";b:1;}' WHERE user_id = '1009'

Comment: Either you have non-printing characters at the front of your SQL, or you are trying to execute multiple SQL statements in one driver call (eg, in PHP `PDO::query`).

Comment: you can avoid \ this way   'a:1:{s:16:"client_special";b:1;}'

Comment: @bishop I'm afraid I don't get you.

Comment: There was a hidden character. It is working now.

Comment: this query runs without error in phpadmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you discovered, and as my comment alluded, non-printing or hidden characters in your SQL statement can lead to unexpected syntax errors.

When confronted with what appears to be ludicrous messages, I find carefully retyping the statement into a different program helps decide whether it is a hidden character issue or a legitimate syntax issue.

It is the act of careful retyping that sanitizes the statement and rules out the non-printing characters. More than once I've done this and I imagine I will continue to do this for the rest of my career!